# Filter date from post meta when date is in string format

Tags: custom-post-types, query-posts, post-meta

I want to filter posts using dates stored in the post meta table. Here is an image that shows how the meta data is being stored:

[image: Date meta data]

I want to filter records between the start date and end date. Here is my query which is not working:

```
$start_date = date('d-m-Y',strtotime($date." +15 days"));
$end_date = date('d-m-Y',strtotime($date." -15 days"));
$query_args['meta_query'][] = array(
    'key' => '_start_date',
    'value' => array($end_date, $start_date),
    'compare' => 'BETWEEN',
    'type' => 'date',
);
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to compare dates in a MySQL statement, you should store dates and times using **MySQL datetime format**: YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS (PHP format `Y-m-d H:i:s`)

Then, you can compare dates easily, and `'type' => 'date'` in the meta query argument should work as expected:

```
$start_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date." +15 days"));
$end_date = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($date." -15 days"));
$query_args['meta_query'][] = array(
    'key' => '_start_date',
    'value' => array($end_date, $start_date),
    'compare' => 'BETWEEN',
    'type' => 'date',
 );
```

If you need to display the date and/or time in a different format, just convert it before display it.

For example, you can use [`date_i18n()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/date_i18n/) to display a localized date, based on WordPress language configuration, in the format you want. For exmple:

```
$post_id= 45;
$start_date = get_post_meta( $post_id. '_start_date', true );
// Format 15 October 2016 = d F Y
// See http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php
echo date_i18n( 'd F Y', strtotime( $start_date ) );
```

Or, if you want to get the date format set in WordPress configuration:

```
echo date_i18n( get_option( 'date_format' ), strtotime( $start_date ) );
```

Comment: Thank you for answer. But it is working project already and i am just editing it so change of format at the time of saving in database not possible. Is their any other possible way we can do that?

Comment: Nothing stops you to update the existent fields in the database to the correct format. Also, note that "The 'type' DATE works with the 'compare' value BETWEEN **only if the date is stored at the format YYYY-MM-DD and tested with this format**." See [WP_Query docs](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#custom-field-post-meta-parameters). Sorry but I'm not going to give another answer, It is up to you to decide to do it correctly or not. I hope you understand.  If not, you may need some query manipulation in plain MySQL, but I have not enough skills in plain MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

For meta_query, tax_query, the array is a nested array because the meta_query accepts optional relations :

so, you need to change the given meta_query to :

```
$query_args['meta_query'] = array(
    //'relation' => 'OR', // Optional, defaults to "AND"
       array(
            'key' => '_start_date',
            'value' => array($end_date, $start_date),
            'compare' => 'BETWEEN',
            'type' => 'date',
       )
);
```

I've commented the relation close, you don't need it with this query.

hope it helps you.

Comment: Note that the code in the question uses `$query_args['meta_query'][]`, not `$query_args['meta_query']`, so it seems to be already an array.

Comment: wouah, I didn't notice the double bracket ! I'm tired today ! I never try to use it like that, maybe it can be better to remove them to test. So I remove them in my answer.